# Can't handle convmv

Tags: mount, conversion, encoding, filenames, fat32

```
Description:    Ubuntu 11.10
Release:    11.10
Codename:   oneiric
```

I have a lot of folders and files with `??? ???? ??.txt` - like file names when I do

```
$ sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/some/folder
```

My external HDD is really fat32. Following a couple of suggestions, I need to

```
$ convmv -f cp1251 -t utf-8 -r --notest folder/
```

but `enca` can't define encoding of the file(s). So, I've tried several encodings by try-and-check and it didn't work. I need to decide which files to delete and which to leave. So,
1) how to mount external HDD fat32 to show filenames correctly? 2) How to convert filenames encoding if I do not know encoding?

**Update**

```
$ sudo dosfsck -a -v /dev/sdc1
dosfsck 3.0.9 (31 Jan 2010)
dosfsck 3.0.9, 31 Jan 2010, FAT32, LFN
open: No such file or directory
```

Rebooting the system and remounting it solved this `magic`. But now I face a problem of

```
rm: cannot remove `somefilehere': Read-only file system
```

As I understand, the filesystem on external HDD is corrupted. Also `dd_rescue` is probably my choice but if I could repair safely, I'd like to.

**update2**
Solved problem partly by

```
$ sudo mount -0 remount,rw /path/to/mountpoint
```

But still can't remove some files.

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /path/to/par
```

causes `: Input/output error`

Answer (score 1):

It *shows* the file names that way, where `?` is the Unix convention for "unknown/non-displayable character". You could:

- You can specify `mount codepage=...` for VFAT
- `ls > somefile`, and then look at the file to try to identify the character coding, perhaps `file` helps
- `od -c` can help too